# How to evaluate JSON Path with fields that contain quotes inside a value?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

I have a NiFi flow that takes JSON files and evaluates a JSON Path argument against them. It work perfectly except when dealing with records that contain Korean text. The Jayway JSONPath evaluator does not seem to recognize the escape "\" in the headline field before the double quote character. Here is an example (newlines added to help with formatting):

```
{"data": {"body": "[이데일리 김관용 기자] 우리 군이 2018 남북정상회담을 앞두고 남
북간 군사적 긴장\r\n완화와 평화로운 회담 분위기 조성을 위해 23일 0시를 기해 군사분계선
(MDL)\r\n일대에서의 대북확성기 방송을 중단했다.\r\n\r\n국방부는 이날 남북정상회담 계기 
대북확성기 방송 중단 관련 내용을 발표하며\r\n“이번 조치가 남북간 상호 비방과 선전활동을
 중단하고 ‘평화, 새로운 시작’을\r\n만들어 나가는 성과로 이어지기를 기대한다”고 밝혔
다.\r\n\r\n전방부대 우리 군 장병이 대북확성기 방송을 위한 장비를 점검하고 있다.\r\n[사
진=국방부공동취재단]\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n▶ 당신의 생활 속 언제 어디서나 이데일리 \r\n▶ 
스마트 경제종합방송 ‘이데일리 TV’ | 모바일 투자정보 ‘투자플러스’\r\n▶ 실시간 뉴스와 
속보 ‘모바일 뉴스 앱’ | 모바일 주식 매매 ‘MP트래블러Ⅱ’\r\n▶ 전문가를 위한 국내 최상의 
금융정보단말기 ‘이데일리 마켓포인트 3.0’ | ‘이데일리 본드웹 2.0’\r\n▶ 증권전문가방송
 ‘이데일리 ON’ 1666-2200 | ‘ON스탁론’ 1599-2203\n＜ⓒ종합 경제정보 미디어 이데일리 -
 무단전재 & 재배포 금지＞ \r\n", 
"mimeType": "text/plain", 
"language": "ko", 
"headline": "국방부 \"軍 대북확성기 방송, 23일 0시부터 중단\"", 
"id": "EDYM00251_1804232beO/5WAUgdlYbHS853hYOGrIL+Tj7oUjwSYwT"}}
```

If this object is in my file, the JSON path evaluates blanks for all the path arguments. Is there a way to force the Jayway engine to recognize the "\"? It appears to function correctly in other languages.

Comment: Hi @Nathan, may you share more info about your workflow? What Processor do you use, and can you give us one jsonPath you try to evaluate? 1- I tried your payload online (https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/), and I get some output when testing `data.headline` or `data.mimeType`.  2- On NiFi, if I use the "EvaluateJsonPath" Processor, 'data.headline' seems to work fine (I see the double-quotes in the extract) but I had to make sure the body was on a single line.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Val_Bonn, I went back to recreate the issue and realized my JSON path selector was trying to select a definite path from a list without providing an index, for example [0]. This was the problem, not escaping quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this after understanding the difference between definite and indefinite paths. The Jayway github README points out the following will make a path indefinite and return a list:

> When evaluating a path you need to understand the concept of when a
>   path is definite. A path is indefinite if it contains:
>
> `..` - a deep scan operator
>
> `?(<expression>)` - an expression
>
> `[<number>, <number> (, <number>)]` - multiple array indexes Indefinite paths
>   always returns a list (as represented by current JsonProvider).

My JSON looked like the following:

```
{
  "Version":"14", 
  "Items":[
    {"data": {"body": "[이데일리 ... \r\n", 
              "mimeType": "text/plain", 
              "language": "ko", 
              "headline": "국방부 \"軍 ... 중단\"", 
              "id": "1"}
    },
   {"data": {"body": "[이데일리 ... \r\n", 
             "mimeType": "text/plain", 
             "language": "ko", 
             "headline": "국방부 \"軍 ... 중단\"", 
             "id": "2"}
   ...
   }
  ]
}
```

This JSON path selector I was using (`$.data.headline`) did not grab the values as I expected. It instead returned null values.

Changing it to `$.Items[*].data.headline` or `$..data.headline` returns a list of each headline.